# How to force Visual Studio to ignore 'System.StackOverflowException'?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, stack-overflow

I've implemented recursive algorithm that can be found under this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12978253/whats-the-fastest-way-to-find-deepest-path-in-a-3d-array).
It works very fine when the 3d array is 10x10x10.

I'm trying to make it run for 200x200x200 array however, Visual Studio says that I might be ussing infinite resursive (I'm pretty sure my prog is OK). Is there any way to handle that? I've tried putting `[DebuggerNonUserCode]` right before the recursive method, but it haven't worked.

Forgot to mention, it's Visual Studio 2010.

Here's recursive function from my program. I'm running that for every cell, that is marked as Unvisited.

```
    public static int tmp_lowest_floor = 0;
    public static int tmp_maks_size = 0;

    static void function1(Point[, ,] array, int pos_y, int pos_z, int pos_x) // recursive function
    {
        Point cell = array[pos_y, pos_z, pos_x];

        if (cell.Visited == false && cell.IsCave)
        {
            cell.Visited = true; // changing to visited so we do not count anything for this cell anymore
            tmp_maks_size++; // increasing for each cell in this cave (in this run)

            if (tmp_lowest_floor < pos_y) { tmp_lowest_floor = pos_y; }
            cell.FillNeighbourList(array, pos_y, pos_z, pos_x);// adds neighbours into cell's list (max 6) up, down, north, east, south, west

            foreach (Point p in cell.neighbours) // max 6 times recursion in here (I know it sounds horrible, but once I check all the neighbours for a cell, I'll not have to check it ever again)
            {
                if (p != null)
                {
                    if (p.IsCave == true && p.Visited == false)
                    {
                        function1(tablica, p.pos_y, p.pos_z, p.pos_x);
                    }
                }
            }

        }

    }
```

p.s.
I know I can do it in a iterative way, however, the homework says it has to be done with recursion

Comment: You can't ignore a StackOverflowException. Implement the algorithm non-recursively.

Comment: StackOverflow is an error, not a warning.  You can't ignore.

Comment: Not only can you not ignore this, now should you ever.

Comment: Even if you found a way to make it ignore a `StackOverflowException`, you'd probably just start corrupting other memory on your computer, which I'm sure is not what you want.

Comment: @Patryk - Post your code so we can address your real problem.

Comment: @Ramhound I've pasted my code :P

Comment: @Patryk - Does your homework say it needs to be done with a 200x200x200 grid?  If so, you need a different algorithm.  Probably a less-efficient but less-memory-intensive one.

Comment: Same happens when I'm using 80x80x80 grid and from what I've heard, teacher was checking algorithms with such files. Homework clearly says it has to be done with recursion :(

Comment: The processor's accumulator can only hold a number going up to a certain value (a multiple of 2, varies with the processor) and a Stack Overflow error occurs if you attempt to use a value larger than is supported in the processor's accumulator.

Answer (score 7):

You can't ignore it, you literally blew the stack.

What you do is either increase the stack (thus delaying the problem) or realize the issue at hand is a really terrible implementation of an algorithm and fix that instead (say, by using an iterative approach, or taking advantage of tail-call recursion).

As an aside, want to know how much stack you're using to go through every cell in a 200x200x200 array just keeping track of your x, y and z coords and nothing else? 96MB. Windows gives you a 1MB wide stack by default.

Edit: To fix your specific problem, what you have is a very basic fill algorithm. The iterative form of it uses a queue and a list. In pseudo-code:

```
list visited=[];
queue q=[];

q.push(startnode);           // the starting point
while(!q.empty())
{
  // make sure we don't revisit nodes
  if(visited.contains(node))
     continue;

  visited.add(node=q.pop()); // we just visited the top

  // do your conditions here, the cave thing? no clue what that is
  // if it passes your filter, do any extra operations on your node here (none in your code)

  // and push the neighbours in the queue
  q.push_all(node.get_neighbours());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for code that uses iteration. Unfortunately, I must use recursion. Thats the homework...

Answer (score 4):

The runtime environment has a finite stack. Every time you call a method, more data gets added to that stack. Every time the method returns, data gets removed from the stack. If you keep calling methods within methods within methods and those methods aren't returning, eventually your stack will run out of space, and you will get a Stack Overflow.

If you want to avoid this, you really just need to modify your algorithm to use less recursion (calling methods within methods), or be content with using a small enough data set that your stack doesn't grow too large.

Answer (score 1):

You can increase you stack size by:

- Right click on your project
- Choose Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> System
- Set different values for 'Stack Reserve Size' and 'Stack Commit Size'(in bytes). From here you can also change the Heap size.

[I had similar issue with tail recursion in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32523171/recursion-in-visual-studio).