# Recursion in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, memory, parameters, int, short

When I run this very simple recursive code, I found out that when the function "recursCheck()" is using integer parameters my memory jumps to 200 MB in Win32 mode and 45 MB in x64 mode, and when the parameter is of type "short" the used memory is 4.7 MB Win32 mode and 1.7 MB for x64. sizeof(int) shows 4 bytes and sizeof(short) shows 2 bytes. How is this possible - 1 000 000 x 2 bytes = 2 MB and 1 000 000 x 4 bytes = 4 MB NOT 200 MB !!! ***So why this problem appers(short vs int) and why Win32 mode takes less memory than x64?*** I`m using Visual Studio 2013, 64 bit OS Windows7, CPU i5, 4 GB RAM. The same issue happens in Visual Studio 2008, but there even more memory is taken - 400 MB instead of 200 MB.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#define SIZE_T_T 1000000
using namespace std;

void recursCheck(int i);

int main()
{
    //cout << sizeof(int) << endl;
    int i = SIZE_T_T;
    recursCheck(i);

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

void recursCheck(int i)
{
    //cout << i << endl;
    if (i != 0)
    {
        recursCheck(--i);
    }
    else
    {
        system("PAUSE");
    }
}
```

Win32 MODE WITH "i" of type "int":
[image 1](http://postimg.org/image/80bcc8gyp/)
Win32 MODE WITH "i" of type "short":
[image 2](http://postimg.org/image/3k4r4c8s5/)

I also found out that before the second system("PAUSE") before the end of the main program the memory IS STILL in use. I know C++ doesn`t manage memory, but shouldn`t when all "recursCheck()" functions end the token memory be freed? I lose the point of LOCAL variable. How you see the parameter is passed BY VALUE. SHOULDN`T IT BE FREED AFTER FUNCTION END AUTOMATICALLY?

Comment: A `short` can't hold the value 1000000 so it will likely recurse fewer times.

Comment: Oh yes that is right now I see, and why so much memory is taken by integers when they are 4 bytes and why in x64 mode tooken memory is less than Win32 and why memory is still taken before return 0; of main function???

Comment: It's not just the arguments that are pushed on the stack; the return address is also pushed, and the compiler might also generate code to set up stack frames for each function call. Which optimization level are you building at?

Comment: @nicksona, what build you use: debug or release?

Comment: I have used Debug. WoW when I use release it actually drops to 1 MB.

Comment: Release mode likely includes the tail-call recursion optimization to prevent the stack from growing.

Comment: @Matthew The recursive part doesn't do anything, so it's actually optimized out completely in release mode. The body of `recursCheck` is reduced to the call to `system`, which is itself optimized into a tail call on `x64` (I was quite impressed by this last part to be honest).